# Evaluate concatonated operator with numbers

Tags: php, operators, eval, concatenation

I'm struggling with a small piece of code that doesn't want to evaluate itself :

```
$t = 5;
$s = "<=";
$r = 6;

var_dump($t.$s.$r);
```

Here the var_dump return `"5<=6"` which make sense but I just want it to tell me **if 5 is inferior or equal to 6 with a boolean**.

I wanted to know if there was an other way to get this boolean beside using an `eval()` or a switch throught all the possible operator

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What complexity is the input going to reach? Is it just arithmetic? Always 2 operands?

Comment: Yes always one number, one operator (<= , < , >=, >), another number

Comment: You might want to look into something like [Symfony's ExpressionLanguage component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html), which allows evaluation of arbitrary calculations but will also deal with sanitisation/validation/etc.

Comment: if its always `x op y` then a simple `switch` is the thing to do, other approaches would be significant overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a safe and flexible solution, this allows you to define a method which is executed depending on the operator matching the key in an array, it only works with two operands, but the last one in the examples `#` just multiplies the first value by 4 and returns the value...

```
$operators = [ "<=" => function ($a, $b) { return $a <= $b;},
    "<" => function ($a, $b) { return $a < $b;},
    ">=" => function ($a, $b) { return $a >= $b;},
    ">" => function ($a, $b) { return $a > $b;},
    "#" => function ($a) { return $a * 4; }];

$t = 5;
$s = "<=";
$r = 6;
var_dump($operators[$s]($t,$r));

$s = "<";
var_dump($operators[$s]($t,$r));

$s = ">=";
var_dump($operators[$s]($t,$r));

$s = ">";
var_dump($operators[$s]($t,$r));

$s = "#";
var_dump($operators[$s]($t,$r));
```

gives...

```
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/t1.php:14:
bool(true)
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/t1.php:17:
bool(true)
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/t1.php:20:
bool(false)
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/t1.php:23:
bool(false)
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/t1.php:26:
int(20)
```

It's a bit convoluted, but also extensible and safe.

Comment: It's also about as efficient and flexible as using switch - only you store the different functions in an array instead of hard-coded in case-statements.

Comment: It's debatable if it's any better than a `switch` as a `switch` is much more direct, but like a lot of solutions it's sometimes down to the semantics of what you want to achieve

Comment: agreed! I don't quite understand why the OP ruled out switch as it is the most direct approach (besides eval) to the problem at hand - but nevertheless he did.

Answer (score 0):

while it is generally not a good idea to have code usch as this (evaluating code that is sstored as plaintext), there is a function for exactly this: `eval()`.

`eval()` does what you expect PHP to do naturally: evaluate valid code stored in a string.

`eval("var_dump(".$t.$s.$r.");");` will do the job - however, since any code inside those variables is executed without question, it can be a security risk, or at least introduce some hard-to-debug errors.
(the extra quoting and the `;` are needed to make the code inside eval actually valid PHP code)

Comment: I know that eval() could do the work but regarding how unsecure eval is I'd wanted to know if there was an other way to calculate this expression

Comment: The question says besides using eval or switch.

Comment: OOps, I missed that part. Well, then there is no other ways that do not either have the same drawbacks as using eval or the same efficiency as using switch.